# Sql server map action to state to get the right result

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

For a database I need to log a state from the action of a different table.

Table 1

| ID | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Accept |
| 2 | Save |
| 3 | Withdraw |
| 4 | Accept |

Table 2

| ID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |

Result
Table 2

| ID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Accepted |
| 2 | Draft |
| 3 | Withdrawn |
| 4 | Accepted |

I was thinking of using a CASE WHEN query to solved this like:

```
Update table 2
set state = action
from (select 
       case when action == Accept then Accepted
            when action == save then draft
            when action == withdraw then withdrawn
        end
      from table 1
)
```

I was wondering if this is the best way or if its possible to use some sort of mapper for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should maintain some kind of junction table which maps actions in `Table1` to states in `Table2`.  Consider:

Table2

| ID | State |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Accepted |
| 2 | Draft |
| 3 | Withdrawn |

```sql
UPDATE t2
SET State = t12.State
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table12 t12
    ON t12.ID = t2.ID;
```