# Update record after checking the values of previous records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my state records in my table

```
before
| ID | Action   | AddedOn  | State     | 
| 1a | Save     | 1-1-2020 |           |
| 1a | Save     | 2-1-2020 |           |
| 1a | Save     | 3-1-2020 |           |
| 1a | Save     | 4-1-2020 |           |
| 1a | Accept   | 5-1-2020 |           |
| 2a | Withdraw | 1-1-2020 |           |
| 2a | Save     | 2-1-2020 |           | 
| 2a | Accept   | 3-1-2020 |           |
| 3a | Save     | 1-1-2020 |           | 
| 3a | Accept   | 2-1-2020 |           |
| 3a | Save     | 3-1-2020 |           |

after
| ID | Action   | AddedOn  | State     | 
| 1a | Save     | 1-1-2020 | Draft     |
| 1a | Save     | 2-1-2020 | Draft     |
| 1a | Save     | 3-1-2020 | Draft     |
| 1a | Save     | 4-1-2020 | Draft     |
| 1a | Accept   | 5-1-2020 | Accepted  |
| 2a | Withdraw | 1-1-2020 | Withdrawn |
| 2a | Save     | 2-1-2020 | Withdrawn | 
| 2a | Accept   | 3-1-2020 | Accepted  |
| 3a | Save     | 1-1-2020 | Draft     | 
| 3a | Accept   | 2-1-2020 | Accepted  |
| 3a | Save     | 3-1-2020 | Accepted  |
```

I made a table that has all the needed states when a certain action is done ( like accept = accepted etc). The only difference is the save action.

When a record has the save action and it is the first in it's group (ID), it will have the draft state. If its not the first record in its group it will take the state of the record before. So in 1a that would be draft but for 2a it is withdrawn.

The statement I so far is:

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    table.State = (select (CASE 
            WHEN (table.Action = 'Save') AND LAG(table.Action,1) OVER (PARTITION BY taskEntityId ORDER BY ActionOn) IS NULL THEN 'Draft' 
            ELSE map.State
            END 
            ) 
from table left join Map on map.Action = table.Action
)
from table left join Map on map.Action = table.Action
```

I tried a lot of different ways to do the third step but i cant find the right query.

The step has to check the previous actions of the same id. If all of them are save, it is a draft, else take the state of the last non save action.

Comment: How is this any different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69581865/sql-server-map-action-to-state-to-get-the-right-result)?

Comment: the previous question talked about mapping from an action to a state. This one is about checking the action of the previous records. If all the previous records are save, it has to be draft. If one of them is ,for example, accept, the current save has to say accept. This is not something i can put in a table because save can have many different states. The others only have 1

Comment: why 1a has all  Draft then ?

Comment: @AliFidanli because when a record has the save action and it is the first in it's group (ID), it will have the draft state. And until a different action happens, it will stay draft. After that , every save will be the state of the last action that wasn't draft

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH PrevActions
AS
(
    SELECT ID, [Action], AddedOn, [State]
        ,LAG([Action]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AddedOn) PrevAction
    FROM YourTable
)
,Results
AS
(
    SELECT ID
        ,SUBSTRING
        (
            -- Max ignores NULLs
            MAX
            (
                CONVERT(varchar(8), AddedOn, 112)
                    + CASE
                        WHEN PrevAction IS NULL
                            AND [Action] = 'Save'
                        THEN 'Draft'
                        WHEN [Action] = 'Save'
                            OR PrevAction = [Action]
                        THEN NULL
                        ELSE [Action]
                    END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AddedOn)
            ,9, 50
        ) AS [Action]
        ,AddedOn, [State]
    FROM PrevActions
)
UPDATE R
SET [State] = ISNULL(M.[state], R.[Action])
FROM Results R
    LEFT JOIN Map M
        ON R.[Action] = M.[Action];
```